# Selenium-Python-ChromeBrowser Launch works when executed in python IDE but it does not when executed from PyDev(Eclipse)

Tags: python, eclipse, google-chrome, selenium

## Software Details

1. Operating System: Mac OSX EL Capitan
2. Eclipse Neon.3 Release (4.6.3)
3. Python Interpreter: 3.6
4. Chrome Version:  63.0.3239.132
5. Chrome Driver Version: ChromeDriver 2.35

When executed below selenium-python code from python IDLE chrome launches gmail.com successfully.
**Where as when executed from PyDev(Eclipse) chrome launches gmail.com and  browser is closed immediately.Please advice what could be the issue and probable solution**

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os
class pySelChrome():
    '''
    classdocs
    '''


    def openChrome(self):
        '''
        Constructor
        '''
        chromeDriverPath = "/Users/XX/Documents/workspace/PySelenium/pySelPack/chromedriver"
        os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"]=chromeDriverPath
        os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"]="/Users/XX/Documents/workspace/PySelenium/pySelPack/chromedriver"
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromeDriverPath)
        driver.get("http://gmail.com")
        driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        driver.fullscreen_window()
        return driver
        

psc = pySelChrome()
psc.openChrome()
```

---

But the same code without class definition works fine in PyDev(Eclipse).

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os

chromeDriverPath = "/Users/XX/Documents/workspace/PySelenium/pySelPack/chromedriver"
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"]=chromeDriverPath
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"]="/Users/XX/Documents/workspace/PySelenium/pySelPack/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromeDriverPath)
driver.get("http://gmail.com")
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.fullscreen_window()
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct Class definition syntax should be: `class ClassName:` rather than `class CLassName():`, remove the `()`.

And you missed the `main()` function as the entry if run as script.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # execute only if run as a script
    psc = pySelChrome()
    psc.openChrome()
```

Comment: I removed (): Still the same issue when executed from eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue even when I removed () from class definition. Also added main method. Please see below code and advice.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os



class pySelChrome:
    '''
    classdocs
    '''


    def openChrome(self):
        '''
        Constructor
        '''
        chromeDriverPath = "/Users/XX/Documents/workspace/PySelenium/pySelPack/chromedriver"
        os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"]=chromeDriverPath
        os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"]="/Users/XX/Documents/workspace/PySelenium/pySelPack/chromedriver"
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromeDriverPath)
        driver.get("http://gmail.com")
        driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        driver.fullscreen_window()
        return driver


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # execute only if run as a script
    psc = pySelChrome()
    psc.openChrome()
```